# Create Firebase "multiple websites" via CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I'm looking for a CLI command to automate the creation of multiple websites:

[image: Multiple websites via GUI]

It looks like there is CLI hosting support but this is limited to "preview channels":

```
hosting:channel:create [options] [channelId]              create a Firebase Hosting channel
hosting:channel:delete [options] <channelId>              delete a Firebase Hosting channel
hosting:channel:deploy [options] [channelId]              deploy to a specific Firebase Hosting channel
hosting:channel:list [options]                            list all Firebase Hosting channels for your project
hosting:channel:open [options] [channelId]                opens the URL for a Firebase Hosting channel
hosting:clone <source> <targetChannel>                    clone a version from one site to another
hosting:disable [options]                                 stop serving web traffic to your Firebase Hosting site
```

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/tree/master/src/commands

I also couldn't find a relevant hosting command in the source code of Firebase tools. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [adding additional sites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#add_additional_sites) it seems that adding sites right now is only supported through the Firebase console.

I'd recommend filing a feature request on the Github repo.

Comment: Thanks, I submitted a feature request via the Firebase website.

Comment: I recommend filing it on the Github repo, as that's more focused.